# how many bits is allocated for an integer when allocating on heap

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have been tinkering with C++ lately and I allocated memory for an integer like this:

```
int* p = new int;
```

As I thought, an integer is usually 4 / 3 bits depending on the system architecture,
but when printing the size of the memory that this pointer allocates:

```
cout << sizeof p << " is the size of an int" << endl;
// output: 8 is the size of an int
```

Why is that so?
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what makes you think that an `int` occupies 4 / 3 bits?

Comment: You are printing size of pointer variable, not of the allocated memory. I don't think there's any standard way to see whole memory allocated with `new`/`new[]`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'm sorry for asking, but do you know why the pointer variable is that big? Just curious.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-data-types/

Comment: it says "typically 4 **bytes**" not **bits**. Anyhow, that site is know for misleading and/or wrong information. See here for sizes of fundamental types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: 64 bits are needed to address the whole possible memory in x64 architecture. x32 architecture would have 32-bit pointers, but this is not enough anymore for modern computers.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ooh I mistaked bits for bytes. rookie mistake haha. thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bits occupied by an `int` is `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)`.
`#include <climits>` to get the constant `CHAR_BIT` defined.

Though in the modern world you're very likely to find `CHAR_BIT` is 8 except some specialised hardware. On some digital signal processing devices it may even be 64.

I think you may have confused 'bit' (binary digit 0 or 1 )and 'byte'.
You've also confused `int` and pointer to `int` in your example.

However, be warned. Logically `new int` allocates that much space for **you** to use, but typically more memory is allocated 'behind the scenes' for "housekeeping" and possibly "alignment".

I won't go into to that too far, but you might find allocating an `int` consumes something like 32 or even 64 bytes of the computers memory until you call `delete` on it.

Comment: now this is what i needed, thank you so much for your answer. I know I kind of confused bits and bytes haha. my bad :P 
Anyways, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

You mistake several things here:
`sizeof p` gives you the size of `p` which is not an `int` but an `int*` i.e. a POINTER to an integer. How big an integer or a pointer to an integer is, depends on the machine i.e. implementation you are currently working on, basically a function of compiler, architecture, operating system, operating mode, and so on. Also I think you mean bytes i.e. octets not bits.

Also the size of any type does not depend on what ever its allocated on the "heap" i.e. with dynamic storage / new / malloc or on the "stack" i.e. with automatic storage duration.

In the end: The size of an `int` regardless if its on the heap, is guaranteed  to be at least 16 bits or 2 octets. As a byte usually consists, but don't have to, out of 8 bits, it's also 2 bytes. To actually print the size in your code example you have to take `sizeof (*p)`

Comment: Now I understand it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof p prints the size of the pointer. sizeof p=8 indicates a 64-bit architecture. On most current architectures, an int will be 4 bytes, or 32 bits. You can print the size of an int either using sizeof(int) or sizeof(var), where is var is variable. Also, are you sure you need to allocate the int? Often, you can just place it on the stack, where it will be deleted automatically, by just writing

```
int p = 0;
```

Comment: Great explaination, thanks for answering!